# When switching from Mojave to Ubuntu, then back to macOS, I cannot reinstall Mojave

Tags: macos, unix, mojave

I had to switch from macOS to Linux momentarily for a short project and now that I'm done, I want to go back to macOS. Prior to installing Ubuntu on my Mac, I was running Mojave as my OS. I tried switching back to Mojave, but when I press **⌘R** to enter recovery mode, only option you are given is Mountain Lion, so I installed it. Now when I tried going back to Mojave I am having the following problems:

When I click Get in App Store to download Mojave, and enter my password and email correctly I get following window:

[image]

Which is followed up by this pop-up:

[image]

Upon clicking LEARN MORE, it redirects me to this Apple Support site:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208104 ("Learn about changes that might prevent you from editing your payment method or accessing the App Store and iTunes Store.")

But, my account has previously been used with App Store, and I also have all payment information down on my Apple ID. Any ideas how to switch back to Mojave?

I have tested this App Store issue by trying to install some other random app, so this truly is an App Store issue and not incompatibility problem of going from Mountain Lion to Mojave

Comment: AFIK you need at least Sierra to upgrade to Mojave.

Comment: I have read somewhere that Mountain Lion is the last one that supports the switch to Mojave, but if that is not the case, is there a way for me to switch from Mountain Lion to some OS from which I can switch to Mojave?

Comment: I though you needed to be running at least El Capitan before Mojave. To get El Capitan, try this Apple website [How to upgrade to OS X El Capitan](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206886)

Comment: I have tried already upgrading to El Capitan and when I try to get it from the App Store, I get this error "This version of OS X 10.11 cannot be installed on this computer."

Comment: @David Anderson, At [https://www.apple.com/macos/how-to-upgrade/](https://www.apple.com/macos/how-to-upgrade/) Apple states "... if your Mac is running OS X Mountain Lion 10.8 or later, you can upgrade directly to macOS Mojave."

Comment: Just install Mountain lion and then upgrade to Mojave's

Answer (score 2):

You used the startup keys <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> which is for ["Install the latest macOS that was installed on your Mac"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904#recovery). Evidently, this was Mountain Lion which you installed without an Apple Id. The startup keys <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> are for ["Upgrade to the latest macOS compatible with your Mac"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904#recovery). This should be Mojave and I would assume no Apple Id would be required.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this here (for obvious reasons) but the issue seems to be related to the payment information of your account which you can't change from devices running old versions of macOS (due to the reasons explained in the support article you've linked).

One possible way out of this is to find a friend running a recent version of macOS or Windows, install iTunes on their computer if needed and then log into your store account within iTunes to review/update payment details. Don't forget to log out of your account again afterwards.

If this fails, you can also contact Apple Support via the means listed on https://www.apple.com/contact/.

Comment: I realize there are problems getting into the App Store, but the OP seems to want Mojave. So, is not the real problem that instead of using ⌘-R, the OP should have used Option-⌘-R?

Comment: @DavidAnderson How would that help here?

Comment: Well, the OP used the startup keys ⌘-R which is for ["Install the latest macOS that was installed on your Mac"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904#recovery). Evidently, this was Mountain Lion which the OP installed without an Apple Id. The startup keys Option-⌘-R are for "[Upgrade to the latest macOS compatible with your Mac"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904#recovery). This should be Mojave and I would assume no Apple Id would be required.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Post it as an answer :-) The problem with both approaches is that we can't verify them, only the OP can.

Comment: Bit confused then, as ⌘-R should reinstall the latest version of macOS that WAS installed... so if Jakov had Mojave installed, why did system still have a Mountain Lion recovery partition? I've never had recovery partition install a macOS version older than the one running from HDD. Unless he installed Mountain Lion first?

Comment: @dr.nixon: There was no recovery partition. The computer booted to internet recovery. Since there was no OS X or macOS, installed, the latest version was version the computer was originally shipped with. I assume this was Mountain Lion.